# finds all the paths between a group of defined vertices in datastax dse graph

Tags: datastax, datastax-enterprise, gremlin, datastax-enterprise-graph, datastax-search

According to
[this](http://tinkerpop.apache.org/docs/3.2.1-SNAPSHOT/recipes/)
the following query:

```
g.V(ids).as("a").repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath()).times(5).emit(hasId(within(ids))).as("b").filter(select(last,"a","b").by(id).where("a", lt("b"))).path().by().by(label)
```

does not work in datastax graph because the `lt("b")` part cannot work on datastax id which is a json format

```
{
    '~label=person',
    member_id=54666,
    community_id=505443455
}
```

How can I change the  lt("b) part in order the query to work ?

Please help

Answer (score 3):

You can pick any property that is comparable. E.g., if all your vertices have a `name` property:

```
g.V(ids).as("a").repeat(bothE().otherV().simplePath()).times(5).
    emit(hasId(within(ids))).as("b").
  filter(select(last,"a","b").by("name").where("a", lt("b"))).
  path().by().by(label)
```